# How to troubleshoot 'Target named Validate not found in the project' error in Jenkins when using mono to build a .NET project?

Tags: asp.net, git, jenkins, mono, devops

Started by user
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test
The recommended git tool is: git
using credential gitea

> git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/.git # timeout=10
> Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url https://**********/SarahTech/ST-BLIP-DOTNET.git # timeout=10
> Fetching upstream changes from https://888888888/ST-BLIP-DOTNET.git
> git --version # timeout=10
> git --version # 'git version 2.25.1'
> using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials
> git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https:///ST-BLIP-DOTNET.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
> git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
> Checking out Revision f8d69fd1a48f55a3a8c0af1f26cfcd4016adbfa2 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f f8d69fd1a48f55a3a8c0af1f26cfcd4016adbfa2 # timeout=10
> Commit message: "lucky draw, and summary"
> git rev-list --no-walk f8d69fd1a48f55a3a8c0af1f26cfcd4016adbfa2 # timeout=10
> [Test] $ /bin/sh /tmp/jenkins1251919285285703516.sh
> /tmp/jenkins1251919285285703516.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to /home/ubuntu/path of proj/STD/STD.csproj
> total 44
> drwxr-xr-x  7 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 27 09:42 .
> drwxr-xr-x  5 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 30 06:58 ..
> drwxr-xr-x  8 jenkins jenkins 4096 Jun  3 09:01 .git
> -rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins 6901 May 27 09:42 .gitignore
> drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 27 09:42 BusinessManager
> drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 27 09:42 BusinessObject
> drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 27 09:42 DataLayer
> -rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins   18 May 27 09:42 README.md
> drwxr-xr-x 25 jenkins jenkins 4096 May 27 09:42 STD
> -rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins 3250 May 27 09:42 STD.sln

> > > > xbuild tool is deprecated and will be removed in future updates, use msbuild instead <<<<

XBuild Engine Version 14.0
Mono, Version 6.8.0.105
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors

Build started 06/03/2023 09:01:12.

---

Project "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/STD/STD.csproj" (Validate target(s)):
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/STD/STD.csproj: error : Target named 'Validate' not found in the project.
Done building project "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/STD/STD.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
Errors:

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/STD/STD.csproj (Validate) ->

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test/STD/STD.csproj: error : Target named 'Validate' not found in the project.

 0 Warning(s)
 1 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.7101140
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

I had given the path of the project where i cloned my repo in jenkins server but giving this error although i have validate in my cs.pros

Comment: Share the contents of `STD.csproj` please.